# Bootstrap 3: two column text over thumbnail on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a blog template but I'm having problems with my view in mobiles.

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[image]

As you can see the text is all over the thumbnail.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-8">

<div class="post-list">
    <?php $myposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1' );
    foreach( $myposts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ) ?>

        <div class="media" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
          <div class="media-left img-responsive">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <div style="border-top:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding-top:10px;">
                <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <p>
             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

 </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">

  <h1>Right column here</h1>

  </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `.media-left` and `.img-responsive` in the same class.

Also I suggest to use `.media-object` class in `the_post_thumbnail()`.